# get value from a link without clicking it?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to show a jQuery alert by hovering on different links with different ids.

I want to tailor the alert based on each link hovered over. These links are created dynamically from a table...

Each link has a different id attribute, so I was thinking to have alert for each without having to click on the link.

For example: a link might have `index.php?id=1` So I want to show an alert on hover that says This is an alert for link 1, etc.

---

**Edit 1:**

The div:

```
echo '<div class="trigger">';
            echo "<a class='trigger' href='".INDEX.'?categ='.$_GET['categ'].'&action='.$_GET['action'].'&subaction=viewlevels'.'&levelid='.$compi['Competence_ID']."'>";
            echo '<img class="linkki" src="'.KUVAT.'paivita.gif" alt="'._("tiedot").'" title="'._("What is this?").'"/></a>';
            echo '<div id="pop-up">';

            echo" <h3>Pop-up div Successfully Displayed for".$_GET['levelid'].
                    "</p></div>";
```

**Edit 2:**

```
<head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        $('.trigger').mouseover(function() {
               alert("You are hovering over " + $(this).attr('href').match(/id=([0-9]+)/)[1]);
            });

        </script>
```

But it always tells me that levelid is undefined..( of course because the form has not been sent)

Comment: Totally possible. What have you tried so far? Post your current code.

Comment: Change your anchor tag to have `class` "trigger" and put the id in the `id` field. (There can be no more than one tag with a certain ID, so your HTML is invalid). If that is not possible, check [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values) on how to parse GET parameters in javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use jQuery's [mouseover()](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) for this:

```
$('.trigger').mouseover(function() {
   alert("This is an alert for link " + $(this).attr('href').match(/id=([0-9]+)/)[1]);
});
```

You should change from using ID's to using a common class.

Comment: He said the `id attribute` would be in `href tag` so how will you show the id just by using `this.id`?

Comment: @DeadMan I answered too quickly as I wanted to mention mouseover, will change it up now

Comment: your current answer will alert the full link instead of just id.

Comment: The thing is that the ID is not defined when the page loads the first time !

Comment: @user125697 ok. I am waiting to see your answer

Comment: @Arvind Yes then you can just use a class obviously, that is no excuse for a downvote, I answered the question the user asked I can't change what he wants..

Comment: @user125697 could you please change the answer to match my variables? I am very newbie to jquery.. thanks!

Comment: @auicsc Please change trigger from an ID to a Class

Comment: @user125697 I dont know why now it is not showing any alert anymore

Comment: @auicsc Post all your code you have. Change id="trigger" to class="trigger", give it to every element. Then use my function.

Comment: @auicsc Did you fix it in the end?

Comment: No bro, instead I just used a very "ugly" solution by showing the data in a new window when each link is clicked.. Yet, it would be great if I could do it the way I described in the problem..

Comment: @auicsc Oh man that's unfortunate, I guess you found some solution at least! If I could have a way to test the PHP on my end I'm sure something could be done, it's just a shame it's not just using html/jquery

Comment: Thats really fine:) Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate. Maybe you'll help me with other problems cuz I am sure i'll be posting many haha.

Answer (score 1):

to bind jquery function on a link over of container child element use below code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     jQuery("#container a").each(function() {

         jQuery(this).mouseover(function() {
         alert(jQuery(this).attr('href'));
       });
    });
```

});

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('#aid').mouseover(function(){alert('whatever you want'+this.id)});
```

documentation http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.hover` and that has two callback one when `hover-over` and one for `hover-out.`

```
$('a').hover(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('href'));
},function(){
  alert('hover out');
});
```

Comment: your current answer will alert the full link instead of just id.

Comment: he thing is that the ID is not defined when the page loads the first time !

Comment: @auicsc so make sure your URL has passed `levelid`

Comment: The url should not pass the levelid.. i do not have to click on any of the links, i want to show the info without the url passing any info

Comment: @auicsc i can not get what you want to do...can you please explain it to me..sorry

Comment: @DipeshParmar what i want to do is to actually show a div that will contain specific contain about the link, before it is clicked just by hovering over it. There are several links loaded dynamically

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating links dynamically, then associate attribute class (say sampleclass) and attribute id as (concatenate "link " and id value from database) with each link

Now

```
$(document).redy(function(){
  $(".sampleclass").hover(function(){
     alert("This is " + $(this).attr("id"));
  });
});
```